# How to register an ios app that reads in a file stream via share icon

Tags: file, swift, ios8, xcode6, share

I've been trying to research this but cannot find anything about it perhaps because I am not using all the right terminology and/or keywords.  I don't really know what this would be called in the iOS world, but here is what I am trying to do.

iOS has this Share/upload icon that usually shows up in certain instances.  When you click this it gives you a list of apps you can share to like Messages, Facebook, Twitter, Flicker etc...What I am trying to research is:
(1) How do I register an app (say XYZ) to show up as an option like the apps listed above and is a recipient of whatever file is share to app XYX?

(2) How do I write the app to be able to read any file that is shared/sent to it as a file object?  So that I can do stuff with the file in my app like saving it locally after reading it in?

I am looking to do this in iOS 8 + Xcode 6 + Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Share Extensions", is a huge new feature in iOS8. You can use this link for references and examples.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this lead!!!  Even though I posted this sometime ago, I was still looking for this.